# Is there a better way to create a dictionary with key and value from a list of dictionaries dynamically?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

#### input:

```py
input = [
    {'key': '1', 'value': 'a'},
    {'key': '2', 'value': 'b'},
    {'key': '3', 'value': 'c'}
]
```

#### output

```
{
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
    "3": "c"
}
```

What I've tried:

```py
output = {list(entry.values())[0]: list(entry.values())[1] for entry in input}
print(output) #{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}
```

My question is there a better way of doing this instead of each `entry` get list of values and access to the first or second!

Any suggestion of doing it in a more simple way!

Comment: `dict(map(dict.values, inp))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Only works when the keys are always in the same order as the sample input.

Comment: @blhsing, that's why I always post such as "hacky" solutions as a comment, not as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `entry` is a dict, access the data using the keys, that is how you should manipulate a dict

```
values = [
    {'key': '1', 'value': 'a'},
    {'key': '2', 'value': 'b'},
    {'key': '3', 'value': 'c'}
]

output = {entry['key']: entry['value'] for entry in values}
```

---

`input` is  the python builtin method for reading user input, don't use it as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do:

```
{x["key"]: x["value"] for x in input}
```

But don't use input as a variable name - it overwrites the builtin Python function input.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
output = {entry['key'] : entry['value'] for entry in input}
print(output)
```

But as others have mentioned, don't use "input" as a variable name in python. This term is already built into python, and overwriting it may cause bugs and problems later on.